# Using flutter app as a package for another app

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-localizations

I have app, which already was finished. Now I need to make few white label apps. In order to keep same core code base I want to reuse my existing app as a base for building new apps. I went simple way by adding it as dependency to newly created flutter app. My core app also uses flutter localisation. The problem I have - my white labelled app does not use core's localization files and raises errors like following `Error: The getter 'translations_pages' isn't defined for the class 'AppLocalizations'` How do I force white labelled app to user core's app localisation files?

Comment: It's really hard to suggest without your code. Please share what you've done till now